# Playfair Cipher, keep getting an excetption

Tags: java

I have the following code, but keep getting an error but the file builds ok, Im fairly new at all this.

Like I said the file builds ok, it accepts the inputs 1 & 2 and gives the options but keeps giving me an exception.  It will ask for the keyword, and the plaintext but when it goes to decrypt or encrpt the error below appears.

Sorry about my first attempt at a queston.. Hopefully this is a bit better...

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3   at
>   java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)  at
>   playfair.format(playfair.java:123)    at
>   playfair.Divid2Pairs(playfair.java:135)   at
>   playfair.Encript(playfair.java:187)   at
>   playfair.main(playfair.java:332)*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class playfair {

    private String KeyWord=new String();
    private String Key=new String();
    private char matrix_arr[][]= new char[5][5];

    public void setKey(String k){

        // This function will take the input key from the user
        // Then it'll remove duplication of letters from the key
        // Will add it to the private KeyWord for matrix generation

        String K_adjust=new String();
        boolean flag = false;

        K_adjust = K_adjust + k.charAt(0);

        for(int i=1; i<k.length();i++){

            for(int j=0;j<K_adjust.length(); j++){

                if(k.charAt(i)==K_adjust.charAt(j))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }

            if(flag == false){
                K_adjust = K_adjust + k.charAt(i);
            }
            flag = false;
        }

        KeyWord=K_adjust;
    }

    public void KeyGen()
    {
    // This function adjust the alphabetical letters adding the
    // KeyWord on the beginning of them & then it calls the matrix function

    boolean flag=true;
    char current;

    Key=KeyWord;

    for ( int i=0 ; i<26 ; i++){

        current=(char)(i+97);

        if(current=='j')
        continue;

        for(int j=0 ; j< KeyWord.length() ; j++ ){

            if (current == KeyWord.charAt(j)){

                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag)
        Key=Key+current;

        flag=true;
    }

    System.out.println(Key);
    matrix ();

    }

    private void matrix ()
    {
    int counter=0;

    for (int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++){

        for (int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++){

            matrix_arr[i][j]=Key.charAt(counter);
            System.out.printf("%s ",matrix_arr[i][j]);

            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    }

    private String format(String old_text)
    {
    // This function is to adjust the Text to encrypt
    // It changes all the 'j' letters to 'i' & add 'x' character
    // between repeatable pairs.

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int len = 0;
    String text = new String();
    len = old_text.length();

    //System.out.println(old_text);
    /*** Change all j's into i's *****/
    for (int tmp = 0; tmp < len; tmp++)
    {
        if (old_text.charAt(tmp) == 'j')
        {
            text = text + 'i';
        }
        else
            text = text+old_text.charAt(tmp);
    }
    /**********************************/
    len = text.length();
    /*** Assign 'x' to letters that repeat in a diagram ***/
    for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2){ //run for half of string length

        if (text.charAt(i+1) == text.charAt(i)){ //if char = previous char

            text = text.substring(0, i+1) + 'x' + text.substring(i+1);
        }else{ //not a repeat character, move along
        }
    }
    return text;
    }

    private String [] Divid2Pairs (String new_string)
    {
        String Original = format(new_string);

        int size= Original.length();

        if(size%2!=0){
            size++;
            Original = Original+'x';
        }

        String x[]= new String[size/2];

        int counter=0;

        for ( int i=0 ; i<size/2 ;i++){
            x[i]=Original.substring(counter, counter+2);
            System.out.println(x[i]);
            counter=counter+2;
        }

        return x;
    }

    public int[] GetDiminsions(char letter){

        int []key=new int[2];

        if ( letter == 'j')
        letter='i';

        for (int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++){

                if(matrix_arr[i][j] == letter){

                    key[0]=i;
                    key[1]=j;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        return key;
    }

    public String Encript(String Source)
    { 
        System.out.println("Encription Start");

        String src_arr[]=Divid2Pairs(Source);

        String Code=new String();

        char one;
        char two;

        int part1[]=new int[2];
        int part2[]=new int[2];

        //start on pair by pair
        for (int i=0 ; i< src_arr.length ;i++ ){
            one = src_arr[i].charAt(0);//get first char
            two = src_arr[i].charAt(1);//get second char

            part1 = GetDiminsions(one);//get position of the first char
            part2 = GetDiminsions(two);//get position of the second char

            //check for special cases
            if(part1[0]==part2[0]){//same row

                if (part1[1]<4)
                    part1[1]++;
                else
                    part1[1]=0;

                if(part2[1]<4)
                    part2[1]++;
                else
                    part2[1]=0;

            }

            else if (part1[1]==part2[1]) //same column
            {
            if (part1[0]<4)
            part1[0]++;
            else
            part1[0]=0;

            if(part2[0]<4)
            part2[0]++;
            else
            part2[0]=0;
            }
            else
            {
            int temp=part1[1];
            part1[1]=part2[1];
            part2[1]=temp;
            }

            Code= Code + matrix_arr[part1[0]][part1[1]] + matrix_arr[part2[0]][part2[1]];
            }
        System.out.println(Code);
        return Code;
    }

    public String Decript (String Code){
        System.out.println("Decription Start");

        String Original=new String();

        String src_arr[]=Divid2Pairs(Code);

        char one;
        char two;

        int part1[]=new int[2];
        int part2[]=new int[2];


        //start on pair by pair
        for (int i=0 ; i< src_arr.length ;i++ ){
            one = src_arr[i].charAt(0);//get first char
            two = src_arr[i].charAt(1);//get second char

            part1 = GetDiminsions(one);//get position of the first char
            part2 = GetDiminsions(two);//get position of the second char

            //check for special cases
            if(part1[0]==part2[0]){//same row

                if (part1[1]>0)
                    part1[1]--;
                else
                    part1[1]=4;

                if(part2[1]>0)
                    part2[1]--;
                else
                    part2[1]=4;
            }

            else if (part1[1]==part2[1]) //same column
            {
            if (part1[0]>0)
            part1[0]--;
            else
            part1[0]=4;

            if(part2[0]>0)
            part2[0]--;
            else
            part2[0]=4;
            }
            else
            {
            int temp=part1[1];
            part1[1]=part2[1];
            part2[1]=temp;
            }


            Original =Original + matrix_arr[part1[0]][part1[1]] + matrix_arr[part2[0]][part2[1]];
            }

        System.out.println(Original);
        return Original;
    }
    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        playfair x=new playfair();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a lower case keyword:");
        String keyword = sc.next();
        x.setKey(keyword);
        x.KeyGen();

        System.out.println("To Encrypt enter 1 \nTo Decript enter 2\nTesting both enter anything else:");
        int choosen_value = sc.nextInt();

        if(choosen_value==1)
        { 
            System.out.println("Enter a lower case word to encrypt:");
            String key_input = sc.next();
            String Encripted= x.Encript(key_input);
        }else if(choosen_value==2){
            System.out.println("Enter a lower case word to decrypt:");
            String decripted = sc.next();

            x.Decript(decripted); 
        }else{
            System.out.println("Enter a lower case word to encrypt & decrypt:");
            String key_input = sc.next();

            String Encripted= x.Encript(key_input);
            x.Decript(Encripted);
        }
    }
}
```

Again Many thanks in advance

Comment: try with this - `for (i = 0; i < len-1; i = i + 2)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having problems with playfair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414116/having-problems-with-playfair)

Comment: @James you already have your answer which is good but for future refererence I've edited your question to include indenting, i think you will see how it makes code much easier to read, the ends of functions, ifs, fors etc line up with their starts and nesting is much clearer. You will get a nicer response on SO if you indent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `format` method, in the below loop

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2)
```

`text.charAt(i+1)` is the line causing the problem.

You need to traverse till the `len-1` instead of `len`.

This is because when `i` is exactly `1` than `len`, it'd still execute the `for` loop, but `i+1` in the `charAt()` method will try to fetch the `char` present at the index `len(since i+1 is now equal to len)`, which throws the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the maximum accessible index in a String is `str.length()-1`.

Answer (score 1):

`(i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2)` is causing exception

you might need to do `i<len-1` here.